# UserDetailsService not honored when using @EnableOAuth2Sso and @EnableResourceServer

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-oauth2

I have @EnableOAuth2Sso on my Application class, one WebSecurityConfigurererAdapter with @EnableWebSecurity and one ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter with @EnableResourceServer.

Application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

WebSecurityConfigurererAdapter:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = false)
@Order(1)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/css/**", "/favicon.ico", "/webjars/**", "/error");
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return userDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requestMatcher(
                new OrRequestMatcher(
                        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/"), // index page for public access
                        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/cfhealth"), // public cloudfoundry health endpoint
                        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/error"),
                        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/perf/**")
                ))
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
    }

}
```

ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerOktaConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public RequestContextListener requestContextListener() {
        return new RequestContextListener();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .requestMatcher(new RequestHeaderRequestMatcher("Authorization"))
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated();
    }

}
```

My expectation now was that my custom user details service is taken into account, but it isn't.

There is a way to injecct a custom user details service by overriding the converter and setting it on user token converter, but that overrides the default configuration and creates quite complex code, as shown here:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerPingConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    PingFederateAccessTokenConverter converter;

    @Autowired
    CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer config) {
        config.tokenServices(tokenServices()).resourceId("swissre");
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        DefaultUserAuthenticationConverter userAuthConverter = new DefaultUserAuthenticationConverter();
        userAuthConverter.setUserDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);
        DefaultAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter =
                (DefaultAccessTokenConverter) converter.getAccessTokenConverter();
        accessTokenConverter.setUserTokenConverter(userAuthConverter);
        return new JwtTokenStore(converter);
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestContextListener requestContextListener() {
        return new RequestContextListener();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .requestMatcher(new RequestHeaderRequestMatcher("Authorization"))
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated();
    }

}
```

Now my question: Somebody out there pointing out a possible wrong-thinking on my side, or simply a better, simpler way to inject a user details service when having a resource server configuration in use?

**Addition:**

I realized, that I should add the OAuth2 configuration:

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      client-id: xxxxx
      client-secret: yyyy
      access-token-uri: https://dev-aaaaaa.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default/v1/token
      user-authorization-uri: https://dev-aaaaaa.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default/v1/authorize
      scope: openid profile email
    resource:
      user-info-uri: https://dev-aaaaaa.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default/v1/userinfo
      token-info-uri: https://dev-aaaaaa.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default/v1/introspect
      prefer-token-info: false
```

Comment: If you call the AuthenticationManager and setting the UserDetailsServices will not enable it automatically?    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        try {
            authenticationManagerBuilder
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new BeanInitializationException("Security configuration failed", e);
        }
    }, or maybe apply the filter with `.apply(securityConfigurerAdapter());`

Comment: Thanks for the solution proposal. In which configuration class should I put the PostConstruct method into? and where do I get access to the authenticationManagerBuilder therein?

Comment: You can put on any class that is annotated with `@Configuration`. Could be `SecurityConfig`

Comment: I've opened an issue at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth2-boot/issues/47